# Align vertically two elements in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/zdb1n3fh/9/) I hava a RaphaelJS canvas with a text and a rectangle where both should start at the same x/y coordinates (see that coordinates are 20/20 in both elements).

To align horizontally I use `{ 'text-anchor': 'start' }` but I cannot find the equivalent to align vertically.

How to make both the text and the rectangle start at the same `y` coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: get the text with `getBBox()`, then divide the text height by 2, and add to the rectangle `y` coordinate.